# How to create rectangles of varying dimensions from a multi-point Feature Collection in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, geometry

I have a Shapefile containing point data that has three variables (i.e. name, width, height). I ingested it as a Feature Collection in Google Earth Engine (GEE). I want to make rectangles of varying dimensions using the 'width' and 'height' data in GEE. I do not know how to start doing this. In GEE, the closest thing I can do is to create square buffers around a point using `.buffer()` and `.bounds()` as I show in the sample code below but that is not what I want.

Can anyone advise on how I can code to create geometries of varying dimensions from point data in GEE?
I have made this GEE asset publicly available for anyone to use.

This is the attribute table of the ee.FeatureCollection.

[image]

Here is the [sample code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/73c4eaf0e92ac9cce069783be02a470a) I mentioned that creates a fixed distance square buffer around each point. I am not sure if this can be modified to create rectangles of varying widths and heights according to the values in the attribute table.

```
//  Load point data
var points = ee.FeatureCollection('users/earthorbgis/GEE_help/gee_point_sample');

//  Buffer points to 500 x 500 m squares
var buffer_interval01_MMR = points.map(function(f) {
  return f.buffer(250).bounds(); 
});

//  Create custom rectangles using point data columns Width and Height
//  Unsure how to start ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the result using the same `.bounds()` and `.buffer()` method. Follow these steps:

1. Create buffers of height/2 and width/2
2. retrieve min-max coordinates of the buffers and save it as separate properties in the `points` FeatureCollection
3. Use the saved coordinates to draw rectangles around each point

[Link to complete code.](https://code.earthengine.google.com/573f2a58b54cef3d80d493b00f568d7e)

Example of result:
[image]

Comment: I used your code on a small subset of my data. I created the rectangles and exported them out of GEE as Shapefiles. I inspected them in QGIS and was very happy to see that the solution works exactly as desired. Thank you @kkrao for the crisp, efficient and creative solution!

Comment: The current code results in ee.FeatureCollection as intended. However, it does not preserve the initial information in the 'points' input layer. 

How would I tweak the code such that I would preserve information per feature on the column 'Name'? 

I would like to avoid a spatial join because there may be overlapping rectangles, and would like to just preserve the Name information in the output Feature Collection.

Comment: Since my previous comment is a different question, I will add a new post linking this one.